# accessing elements from nlohmann json

Tags: c++, json

My JSON file resembles this

```
{
  "active" : false,
  "list1" : ["A", "B", "C"],
  "objList" : [
    {
     "key1" : "value1",
     "key2" : [ 0, 1 ]
    }
   ]
}
```

Using nlohmann json now, I've managed to store it and when I do a dump `jsonRootNode.dump()`, the contents are represented properly.

However I can't find a way to access the contents.

I've tried `jsonRootNode["active"]`, `jsonRootNode.get()` and using the `json::iterator` but still can't figure out how to retrieve my contents.

I'm trying to retrieve `"active"`, the array from `"list1"` and object array from `"objList"`

Comment: The answers below don't address the differences between each method.  `get()` returns `copy of value`, `at()` return `ref`, `operator[]` returns `const ref`

Comment: The documentation on this library is so horrible that I ended up opting for another library which is inferior to this but at least it tells you how to do the simplest tasks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following [link](http://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a652414dd930cb3af3b6f454cc535a23e.html#a652414dd930cb3af3b6f454cc535a23e) explains the ways to access elements in the JSON. In case the link goes out of scope here is the code

```
#include <json.hpp>

 using namespace nlohmann;

 int main()
 {
     // create JSON object
     json object =
     {
         {"the good", "il buono"},
         {"the bad", "il cativo"},
         {"the ugly", "il brutto"}
     };

     // output element with key "the ugly"
     std::cout << object.at("the ugly") << '\n';

     // change element with key "the bad"
     object.at("the bad") = "il cattivo";

     // output changed array
     std::cout << object << '\n';

     // try to write at a nonexisting key
     try
     {
         object.at("the fast") = "il rapido";
     }
     catch (std::out_of_range& e)
     {
         std::cout << "out of range: " << e.what() << '\n';
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks that help me ! Can you just past the code you used to access key2 for example ?
You can also mark this topic as resolved.

Comment: Is there no way to convert them to strings? :(

Comment: @BenjaminGoutfer No problem :)

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck It's been a while since I've posted this :\ But I'm pretty sure there is an easy conversion for that

Comment: @JeremyKuah, I ended up using `get` due to knowing the keys by-name and their value-type. Otherwise this would have been annoying... To handle it dynamically I was working around it by iterating the elements, but that was a sloppy hack.

Comment: @JeremyKuah : I would like to add a short guide on what happens if one tries to access a non-existent key. `operator[]()` --> code aborts because of an `assert` violation (in debug mode). `at()` --> Exception `std::out_of_range` is thrown. To get the value safely with a default, use `value(key, default_value)`.

Answer (score 13):

In case anybody else is still looking for the answer.. You can simply access the contents using the same method as for writing to an `nlohmann::json` object. For example to get values from 
json in the question:

```
{
  "active" : false,
  "list1" : ["A", "B", "C"],
  "objList" : [
    {
      "key1" : "value1",
      "key2" : [ 0, 1 ]
    }
  ]
}
```

just do:

```
nlohmann::json jsonData = nlohmann::json::parse(your_json);
std::cout << jsonData["active"] << std::endl;    // returns boolean
std::cout << jsonData["list1"] << std::endl;     // returns array
```

If the `"objList"` was just an object, you can retrieve its values just by:

```
std::cout << jsonData["objList"]["key1"] << std::endl;    // returns string
std::cout << jsonData["objList"]["key2"] << std::endl;    // returns array
```

But since `"objList"` is a list of key/value pairs, to access its values use:

```
for(auto &array : jsonData["objList"]) {
    std::cout << array["key1"] << std::endl;    // returns string
    std::cout << array["key2"] << std::endl;    // returns array
}
```

The loop runs only once considering `"objList"` is array of size 1.

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 3):

I really like to use this in C++:

```
for (auto& el : object["list1"].items())
{
  std::cout << el.value() << '\n';
}
```

It will loop over the the array.