# From a json object/file, how can I derive the values belonging to keys within an array while storing them as a string within a vector?

Tags: c++, json, string, parsing, stdvector

---

### Json object/file sample:

```
{
  "ADMIN_LIST" :[
    {
      "name" : "Luke",
      "age" : 36,
      "id_hash" : "acbfa7acrbad90adb6578adabdff0dcbf80abad43276d79b76f687590390b3ff429"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Sasha",
      "age" : 48,
      "id_hash" : "97acbfa7acrbad90adb6578adabd0dcbf80abad43276d79b76f687590390b3ff429"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Henry",
      "age" : 42,
      "id_hash" : "2acbfa7acrbad90adb6578adabd0dcbf80abad493276d79b76f687590390b3ff429"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Jake",
      "age" : 31,
      "id_hash" : "facbfa7acrbad90adb6578adabd0dcbf80abad432b76d79b76f687590390b3ff429"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Goku",
      "age" : 22,
      "id_hash" : "0acbfa7acrbad90adb6578adabd0dcbf80abad43276d79b76f687e590390b3ff429"
    }
  ]
}
```

Having keys named **`id_hash`** within an array named **`ADMIN_LIST`**, I want to get the value of each instance of **`id_hash`** and store it into a string vector **`std::vector<std::string> Id_Vector = {};`**. As simple as that.

The number of Admins varies from json files/objects.... as such a hard-coded predetermined number of key values needed would not be accurate.

---

### Rules

1. The source of the **json** data can be streamed from a file, **`file.json`** file or a **`file.txt`** containing **json** formatted text.
2. Any **json** library can be used (as long as it is **c++ friendly**)
3. Any **json** library used, should please come with a link to it's **repository or download site**.
4. The use of **for loops** is very much allowed.
5. **Loop used in determining amount of key values to store should be dynamic.**

---

### Sample Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SomeJSON_Library.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> Id_Vector = {};
   for(int g = 0; j <= Length_Of_Keys; j++) // Where Length_Of_Keys refers to the dynamic number of instances within a json file/object
   {
      Id_Vector [j] = FromJson.Array.Keys("id_hash");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Such that a call to any **`id_hash`** index would hold relative value gotten from Json File.

---

### Further Usage of Json Value Parsing

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SomeJSON_Library.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> Id_Vector = {};
   std::vector<std::string> Admin_Name = {};

   for(int j = 0; j <= Length_Of_Keys; j++) // Where Length_Of_Keys refers to the dynamic number of instances within a json file/object
   {
      Id_Vector [j] = FromJson.Array.Keys("id_hash"); // Get value of key "id_hash"
      Admin_Name [j] = FromJson.Array.Keys("name"); // Get value of key "name"
   }

   // For the sake of confirming implemented code
   for(int x = 0; x <= Length_Of_Keys; x++) // Length_Of_Keys or sizeof(Id_Vector[0]) / sizeof(Id_Vector)
   {
      std::cout << "Id Hash of Admin " << Admin_Name[x] << "is " << Id_Vector[x] << "\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

---

### Output

`Id Hash of Admin Luke is acbfa7acrbad90adb6578adabdff0dcbf80abad43276d79b76f687590390b3ff429`

`Id Hash of Admin Sasha is 97acbfa7acrbad90adb6578adabd0dcbf80abad43276d79b76f687590390b3ff429`

`Id Hash of Admin Henry is 2acbfa7acrbad90adb6578adabd0dcbf80abad493276d79b76f687590390b3ff429`

`Id Hash of Admin Jake is facbfa7acrbad90adb6578adabd0dcbf80abad432b76d79b76f687590390b3ff429`

`Id Hash of Admin Goku is 0acbfa7acrbad90adb6578adabd0dcbf80abad43276d79b76f687e590390b3ff429`

---

---

The truth is I'm certain that it's as simple as I've obviously laid it out to be, but I can't for the life of me figure out which Json library or function can do this. I know it's something like  **`FromJsonObj.GetValueFromKey("id_hash");`** but I haven't had any luck figuring out how to go about this.

I really wish I knew of a library with such a straight forward syntax call as  **`FromJsonObj.GetValueFromKey();`**.

I just need an actual **C++** code that implements the illustrated desired result.

Help me out and please don't mark as **DUPLICATE**....Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a well-known library, like https://github.com/nlohmann/json.

Here is an example of how you can access array elements by key:  [accessing elements from nlohmann json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38099308/accessing-elements-from-nlohmann-json)